# Why th:include is no longer recommended since Thymeleaf 3.0?

Tags: thymeleaf

http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#template-layout docs says:

> The code above defines a fragment called copy that we can easily include in our home page using one of the th:insert or th:replace attributes (**and also th:include, though its use is no longer recommended since Thymeleaf 3.0**).

I personally found `th:include` the only possible way to implement templates.

So what does that mean? `th:include` is deprecated or will be removed in future releases? Or it is bad practice?

What makes `th:include` bad reputation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/625 I got response that starting with AttoParser v2.0.3 and corresponding Thymeleaf v3.0.4 `content()` selector can be used, which with `th:replace` makes `th:include` redundant:

```
<div th:replace="thymeleaf/layout :: tmpl(~{::body/content()})">
    XXX
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it's a case of generalising what was previously provided by `th:include` ...

> Thymeleaf 3.0 introduces a new type of expression as a part of the
>   general Thymeleaf Standard Expression system: Fragment Expressions.
>
> They look like this: ~{commons::footer} and yes, they are extremely
>   similar to the syntax that could be used inside th:replace and
>   th:include (now th:insert) since long ago… because they use exactly
>   that syntax, but generalized so that it can now be used in other
>   scopes.

See [Fragment Expressions](https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/451).

There is nothing in the Thymeleaf docs to suggest that `th:include` should not be used nor to suggest that `th:include` will be removed in a future release.

Comment: Its in the documentation that it is no longer recommended and the OP provide the quote "is no longer recommended" along with the source link.